# tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".!combobox"

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estoy creando un programa en *Python* usando la librería *Tkinter*, pero tengo un problema al momento de querer eliminar el "combobox", me salta el siguiente error:

> "tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".!combobox".

He tratado de buscar como eliminar dicho mensaje, pero no me ha resultado.

Mi idea es que al momento de seleccionar la opcion 1, se logre eliminar la variable "lista".

De antemano, Muchas Gracias

Adjunto parte del código

```python
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox, ttk


def grafica():
    if 'label1' and 'label2' in globals():
        label1.destroy()
        label2.destroy()
        botontest.destroy()
        lista.destroy()

        
    if lista.current()==1:
        root.title("Option 1")
        root.geometry('750x150')
        root.config(width=400, height=200)
        cuadro1_op1 = ttk.Entry()
        cuadro1_op1.place(x=50, y=50)
        cuadro2_op1 = ttk.Entry()
        cuadro2_op1.place(x=200, y=50)
        cuadro3_op1 = ttk.Entry()
        cuadro3_op1.place(x=350, y=50)
        cuadro4_op1 = ttk.Entry()
        cuadro4_op1.place(x=500, y=50)
        botonopcion1=Button(root,text="ok",command=grafica)
        botonopcion1.pack()
        botonopcion1.place(x=300,y=90)
        eop1c1=tkinter.Label(text="Product").place(x=85,y=27)
        eop1c2=tkinter.Label(text="Code").place(x=230,y=27)
        eop1c3=tkinter.Label(text="Price").place(x=385,y=27)
        eop1c4=tkinter.Label(text="Date").place(x=520,y=27)
        etiqueta_opcion1= tkinter.Label(root, text="Menu  1", bg="Green", fg="red")
        etiqueta_opcion1.pack(fill = tkinter.X)
        
    else:
        respuesta=messagebox.askretrycancel(message="Select Option", title="FAIL")
        if respuesta:
            return()
        else:
            root.destroy()

root=Tk()
root.title("Title: Hello World")
root.geometry('200x200')

root.title("TEEEEEST") 
label1= tkinter.Label(root, text="TEST", bg="Blue", fg="white") 
label1.pack(fill = tkinter.X) 
label2=tkinter.Label(text="HELLO WORLD 2") 
label2.pack() 


lista=ttk.Combobox(root,width=17)
lista.pack()
lista.place(x=30, y=77)


opciones=['0','1','2']

lista['values']=opciones

botontest=Button(root,text="Test",command=grafica)
botontest.pack()
botontest.place(x=170,y=70)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: No podés interactuar con un Combobox que ya no existe. Te conviene primero obtener el valor, hacer lo que tengas que hacer y recién ahí destruir dicho widget.

Comment: Lo traspase a la interaccion "opcion 1" la destruccion del widget y tambien me aparece el error :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buenas lo mas cercano que encontre a tu pregunta es la funcion `.place_forget()` que sirve para ocultar el objeto,si quieres sacarlo de nuevo usas la funcion `.place ()` nuevamente.
El problema en tu codigo es que vuelves a llamar al combobox despues de haber sido borrado de la memoria.

¿te fue util?

Comment: Me ha servido la funcion .place_forget()... Soy relativamente nuevo usando la libreria "Tkinter". Me parece un poco extraño que se mantenga el combobox en la memoria (aun me aparece en la ventana luego de elegir alguna "opcion") ... Gracias por la ayuda :)